# TikaApp JAR Classes

Tags: apache-tika

I`m using Apache Tika 1.4 to extract content from my documents. But it also comes with org.bouncycastle.* classes, and I use another version of bouncycastle which is conflicting with the Tika packages.

If the Tika was using the bouncycastle (bcprov) jar, I could exclude that using exclusion tag from Maven, but the TikaApp has copied the org.bouncycastle classes into it, so, I cannot exclude them.

There`s some way to remove this package without recompiling or branching Apache Tika and set to use another JAR to this specified package or something like that?

Thanks

Comment: The `tika-app` jar is intended to be used as a standalone program. Is there a reason why you're trying to use it as part of an existing project, instead of using the more normal packages?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're using completely the wrong packaging of Tika!

The `tika-app` jar is a standalone, runnable jar, containing all of the Tika code + all dependencies required to let it run. It's intended to be used from the command line, standalone, to allow non-Java users to call Tika, and to allow for easy testing.

If you're writing your own Java application, which it sounds like you are, you will want to depend on the `tika-core` artifact as a minimum. That contains all the interfaces, the mime detection, service loaders etc. You'll then almost certainly also want to depend on `tika-parsers` , which provides all the code to do the actual parsing of the file formats, along with pulling in their required dependencies. This gives you the full control you seem to want.

Finally, there's also an OSGi bundle available, for those who prefer the control and classloading that OSGi offers, that's in the `tika-bundle` artifact. There's also a CXF powered JAX-RS version, which offers Tika's services over a RESTful interface, that comes in the `tika-server` artifact.